# MySQL 'Subquery returns more than 1 row Error'

Tags: mysql, runtime-error

I have run the following query over 200 times without an error:

```
INSERT INTO tempAbsenceClientUpload SELECT FirstName, LastName, UserID, UserIsActive, Email, TopClient, ClientGroup, isUpdated, MainProcessID, rownumber FROM temporaryAbsClientTable
```

Which simply takes from one table to another.
However, I now get the following error message: `Subquery returns more than 1 row Error`
Can anyone help me to understand why?

I don't really want alternative code suggestions, just why it happened.

Thanks.

Comment: this is not all query?

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from the above query? Because even if the SELECT query return multiple records it will insert multiple records. But won't give the error.

Comment: The entire query is:
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Yes, the error comes from this query- It's run for large tables hundreds of times without error- now this arises..

Comment: I cannot find anything specific to my question in google, but I'm still searching..

Comment: @IainFifer - But there is no sub-query in the above query.

Comment: Perhaps the select statement is the sub query it refers to..?

Comment: The "insert into select from" statement is a single query, there is no subquery here. Is the whole statement exactly as written?

Comment: Yes- I've directly copied and pasted what I entered into the SQL editor and the error that this generated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have duplicates in the second table.
IN that case you could do this to eliminate them:(create a copy of your table first)

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tableName ADD UNIQUE KEY keyName (`columnName`);
```

OR to check for duplicates:

```
select columnNameWithDuplicates, count(*) from tableName group by (columnNameWithDuplicates) having count(*)>1;
```

Answer (score 2):

There was an 'on insert' trigger on the destination table. The data being entered was referenced against a third table in an expression expecting a single result (two results were being generated).

So the 'sub routine' was connected to a function in a trigger on the destination table firing due to the insert.

Thanks for everyone's ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a WHERE clause which is giving this error